# 9 month old Border Collie chasing and staring at the the sun

Tags: dogs, outdoor

We got a Border Collie back in August 2016, and around November she started hunting shadows.

Then around December, she started focusing on lights (for an instance in the roof), but this didn't last long. She still hunts shadows.

Then when the sun came above the horizon again in January (we live in a part of Norway where the sun doesn't go above the horizon for a few months around winter), it didn't take long (around the end of January) for her to start staring at and trying to run towards the sun.

We have tried to distract her from staring, but it is very hard as she then notices shadows. And any tiny thing makes her look up, means she looks back on the sun.

Even when we are outside training or taking a walk, she stares at the sun. Letting her go loose is something we can't do, because she is so focused on the sun she doesn't listen to us.

Here the other day she was so focused on the sun, she walked into a parked car. And yesterday a wall. She stared at the sun while walking forward, into a shadow but continued to stare in the same direction. She did then not look forward which caused her to crash into these objects.

Any ideas as to how I can get her to stop chasing and staring at the sun?

**EDIT 16.05.17:**

The problem still persists, and while training or taking a walk she stares and loses focus on whatever is being done. We have tried training her to get her to stop staring at the sun, but there has been little progress.

Comment: Have you been to the vet with her? It sounds like somethign may be wrong with her eyesight and should get checked.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with her vision (but if she continues staring, it will be a problem). She hunted shadows while the sun was low over the horizon, then when it went higher(so it was visible) she started looking at it. A while back she stared at lights (and reflections), so the reason for her staring is because she is fascinated by lights I suppose. She stares at street lights when they are on too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was at a peak when the sun returned (this far north there is no visible sun during the days). After a while, she started accepting the fact that it was there, and started ignoring it more and more. At this point, the problem is not present. She still stares at the sun some times, but she has started accepting it is there and doesn't constantly stare at it anymore.

Distracting her while outside has also been an important part in training her to not focus on the sun.